# GCP SQL instances connectios with autoscale GKE nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GCP project with multiple SQL instances , and two GKE cluster with auto scaling. I have configured the SQL instances with public ip of the GKE nodes in connections tab, to allow the connection by public IP. My doubt is, when my cluster auto scale up, if I don't add the new public ip node, the pod inside it doesn't connect. Is there a way to add the public ip of the nodes automatically when it are created?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a dedicated public IP to connect to the SQL database? You can have several pod on the same node and reach the same database with the same IP. What's your concern?

Comment: My pods connect to database by public IP (the database are in GCP SQL).

Comment: Yes and? with TCP protocol, you can reach several time the same IP address from the same IP address. Your source port will be different to allow the network interface to dispatch the data to the correct process. I don't understand what worry you. Have a try, you will see, it works!

Comment: My problem is, when mi cluster of GKE auto scale up with new node, I have to add the public IP of the new node in the Allow ip conections in the SQL database. I need a way to automate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your last comment, I understand your problem! So, it's the wrong way, for 2 reasons:

- It's not automatic and hard to handle
- The IP of your node is ephemeral, if you allowlist it, and then you release the IP to the Google Cloud IP pool, another user (bad actor?) that need a public IP could reuse the same IP and access your database!

---

So, you have 2 solutions:

- Firstly, you can use private IP. By this way, you don't have to worry about adding authorized IP. If the IP is in the correct VPC, the routing is automatic (have a look to the firewall rule if it's not the case).
- The other solution is to use a sidecar container with [Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) loaded in it (or load it in your container, but, for a better separation of concern, I prefer the sidecar). This sidecar will establish a secure communication channel with your database and either open a linux socket or open a TCP port for your application. You have a [full example here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine)

In the second scenario, on only need a public IP, no authorized network. The Cloud IAM service check the access and allow the secure tunnel opening. With this solution, it's scalable, and more secure: you don't need a SSL certificate on your database to encrypt the traffic, it's done by default with the Clous SQL auth proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try the sidecar proxy.